# How to reach after 92nd fibonacci numbers in JAVA?

Tags: java, fibonacci

I want to get the 93rd and more Fibonacci numbers in JAVA. In fact, when I try to get Fibonacci numbers as `long`, I get at most the 92nd number. Is there any way to reach 93rd and after?

**Sample Output**

> *91. number= 4660046610375530309*
>
> *92. number= 7540113804746346429*
>
> *93. number= -6246583658587674878*

Here is my code:

```
    long s1 = 0;
    long s2 = 1;
    long current = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
        current = s1 + s2;
        s2 = s1;
        s1 = current;

        System.out.println((i+1) + ". " + current);
    }
```

Comment: you have integer overflow, try using `BigInteger` instead of `long`

Comment: You can use the BigInteger class

Comment: Take a look at `java.math.BigInteger`-class. but don't ask about performance....

Comment: Please check this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/849813/large-numbers-in-java

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a way to reach 93th and after fibonacci numbers. You can use `java.math.BigInteger` library. You can reach large numbers as you can't imagine like 100.000 digits. Here are the steps:

**Add Library**

```
import java.math.BigInteger;
```

**First 10.000 Fibonacci Numbers**

```
BigInteger s1 = BigInteger.ZERO;
BigInteger s2 = BigInteger.ONE;
BigInteger current = BigInteger.ZERO;

for (int i = 0; i < 10000; i++) {
    current = (s1.add(s2));
    s2 = s1;
    s1 = current;
    System.out.println((i+1) + ". " + current);
}
```

Comment: thanks for the answer

Comment: you are welcome @KevinDang

Answer (score 0):

You can use [BigInteger](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html). Take a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29617340/fibonacci-calculator-with-bigintegers).

e.g.:

```
public static BigInteger fib(int n) {
  if (n == 0 || n == 1) {
    return BigInteger.ONE;
  }
  return fib(n - 2).add(fib(n - 1));
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
  for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    System.out.println(fib(i));
  }
}
```

Comment: although is a valid answer, recursion makes program really slow...

Comment: @JordiCastilla the other question I referred has an example with memorization.

Comment: yes, I flagged this question as duplicate using your linked question, I'm just telling that performance is much worst in this case using recursion

Comment: Binet's formula will give the highest performance. http://mathworld.wolfram.com/BinetsFibonacciNumberFormula.html